# How to ensure the current item of a WPF data grid is visible?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid with IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem set to true and binding it to an ObservableCollection. When use a ICollectionView.MoveCurrentTo* method to change the current item the DataGrid changes its current item accordingly.

The problem I'm having is that if the current item is not currently visible the DataGrid does not scroll the current item into view. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to handle `ICollectionView.CurrentChanged` and call `DataGrid.ScrollIntoView(object item)` from it to achieve that.

Comment: Is it possible to provide more details about this? You see my main window sets the collectionviewsource object. But my viewmodel is handling the work of add/edit/delete of selecteditem on the datagrid. So, I do not have access to the datagrid object from here, nor the cvs.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: Collection views are something i would put in the view-model if it needs access to it. Other than that there also is a default view associated with your collection which you can get from anywhere. Not sure if the one you create in the view becomes the default or whether you can register it as the default though.

Comment: I was able to do this in the code behind: `private void gridStudents_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (gridStudents.SelectedItem != null)
                gridStudents.ScrollIntoView(gridStudents.SelectedItem);
        }`